# How to get HTTPS callbacks for Angular ng serve development server

Tags: angular, https, lets-encrypt, ngrok, certbot

I am developing against Jumio NetVerify service, which does not accept custom ports in the URL, but needs a full qualified domain with a real HTTPS certificates.

How am I going to make Jumio NetVerify external service to work against my local Angular development server which I run as `ng serve`?

Answer (score 0):

This is using ngrok Premium subscription which allows you to define your own regions and domain names. Furthermore instructions are for macOS.

Install ngrok and certbot from homebrew.

```sh
brew cask install ngrok
brew install certbot
```

Login to ngrok locally. Get your authtoken from ngrok.io.

```sh
ngrok authtoken ...
```

Do HTTP 80 tunnel for your ngrok **personal** domain:

```sh
ngrok http -region eu -hostname=mikko.eu.ngrok.io 80
```

Now we need to get our certificates issued by Let's Encrypt. Let's assume we are working in an empty directory called `./certs`, where we want to pull in our certificate files.
When the tunnel is running, in another terminal go to a working directory and do:

```sh
cd certs
certbot
certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d mikko.eu.ngrok.io --work-dir . --logs-dir . --config-dir .
```

This will pull in the certificates over the ngrok HTTP 80 tunnel:

```
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /Users/moo/code/token-swap/certs/live/mikko.eu.ngrok.io/fullchain.pem
```

Now we have real HTTPS certs, so we can do `ngrok` tunnel to our local development environment.
Let's assume we are using Angular `ng serve` that runs in port 4200.

Let's start `ngrok` again:

```
ngrok tls -region eu -hostname=mikko.eu.ngrok.io -key certs/archive/mikko.eu.ngrok.io/privkey1.pem -crt certs/archive/mikko.eu.ngrok.io/fullchain1.pem 4200
```

Then start your Angular server:

```
ng serve --public-host mikko.eu.ngrok.io
```

Now you can reach your local Angular development environment through both URLs:

https://mikko.eu.grok.io

http://localhost:4200

More info:

[More tips on ngrok info](https://gist.github.com/seanknox/4c3b457e5bf4895865825d238c32bd1f)

[DigitalOcean CertBot standalone guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates-on-ubuntu-16-04)